# Crystal Report Viewer takes a very long time to run

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

So i've inherited a web application that is using crystal reports to display our reports. I've found that the performance of running a report on the web app too way too long(in come cases over 2-3 mins.)

I have broken down all of the components of the application to find where the data was bottle-necking and it turns out that its the crystalreportsviewer. It is only taking 1-2 seconds to run the stored procedure in the database and at most 4-5 seconds to get the results of our data in our web services. But when i go to run the report using crystal it takes several minutes.

What i would like to know is if there is some kind of bug occurring in the crystal reports viewer or if someone would have any idea on how to go about speeding up the time it takes to load a report using the crystal reports viewer?

I've looked around quite extensively for the answer to this problem which included making changes to the [.net framework](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/f70cad38-dea9-4c4b-a812-9b2f2a7b4c08/) But i was hoping for some insight regarding crystal reports itself as to why this occurs.

any help of suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is it occurring only on the first report load (per app pool)? or is it every report?

Comment: @dotjoe The first one is exceptionally slow (2-3 mins) and every report after or if i try running the same report takes about a minute. But i still feel that, that is way too long of a runtime when everything else takes a few seconds.

Comment: Yea, it definitely is...do the reports run this slow at design time (i.e. when you run them from the VS designer or standalone designer)? I ask because sometimes it can be the report's complicated formatting/grouping/formulas and not the datasource.

Comment: @dotjoe When i do a print preview in crystal reports it takes about 15 seconds the first go around and 6-8 seconds when i run the print preview and time after.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the initial "loading" of the first page right? Nothing related to caching? And you're using CR version 13.0.2?

Comment: @dotjoe well if there are multiple pages in the viewer going to the next page takes just as long as when you load the first page and i believe that the version being used is 12.0.2000.0. I wasn't aware that there was a new viewer available... is 13.0.2 supported in .net 2.0 or would i have to more to a later framework version in order to use it?

Comment: yea, 13.0.2 is the version for .net 3.5+(VS 2010)...probably wouldn't make a difference. I'd guess the bottleneck is somewhere during the Page_PreRender event as this is where CRV does all it's work. Maybe try doing an export (without using the CRV) to verify? or post some of the code used to Load the report and set the datasource.

Answer (score 2):

Crystal reports takes a long time to load its DLLs at the first time you call a report. What SAP suggests is to load a dummy report at the first app excution using a thread or a background worker to get DLLs ready when calling your production reports.
Hope it helps.